# Snowflake upsert from temp stage

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a json data of format:

```
api_data = [{'ID': '1314420000c28b88d31115b9d8530bb1', 'NAME': 'Dummy User', 'STATUS': 'ACTIVE'}]
```

I have these columns.

```
columns = ['ID', 'NAME', 'STATUS']
```

I am loading data to staging area in snowflake as csv files and the inserting data to main table as merge command. Id is my primary key.
Following is my code:

```
def test_merger(self, api_data):
        columns = [x for x in api_data[0].keys()]


        try:
            with TemporaryDirectory(prefix=f'test_USER_') as tmpdir:
                df = pd.DataFrame(api_data)


                df.to_csv(tmpdir + f'/test_USER.csv', sep='^', index=False, columns=columns)


                stage_name = f"USER_{snowflake_client.generate_random_string()}"
                create_stage = f"CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE {stage_name} COMMENT = 'TEMPORARY STAGE FOR USER DATA LOAD'"
                snowflake_client.run("ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';")
                snowflake_client.run(create_stage)

                snowflake_client.run(f"put file://{tmpdir}/* @{stage_name} PARALLEL=16")

                snowflake_client.run(
                    f"MERGE INTO USER USING (SELECT $1  TID, $2  TNAME, $3  TSTATUS FROM @{stage_name})  TEMPSTAGE"
                    f"ON USER.ID = TEMPSTAGE.TID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET USER.NAME = TEMPSTAGE.TNAME, USER.STATUS = TEMPSTAGE.TSTATUS "
                    "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, NAME, STATUS) VALUES (TEMPSTAGE.TID, TEMPSTAGE.TNAME, TEMPSTAGE.TSTATUS);")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"ERROR {e}")
            raise e
```

The csv file is getting created correctly:

```
ID^NAME^STATUS
1314420000c28b88d31115b9d8530bb1^Dummy User^ACTIVE
```

My user table is populated incorrectly as:

```
ID                      NAME                STATUS
ID^NAME^STATUS
```

What I want is:

```
ID                                        NAME                STATUS
1314420000c28b88d31115b9d8530bb1          Dummy User          Active
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a note - this is a great use-case for Snowpipe, Tasks, and Streams.  You'd ingest the data automatically as JSON into Snowflake, and then have a task that merges the data incrementally as you receive the data.  This avoids passing the data through a dataframe on the way to Snowflake and all of the execution is handled as a scheduled task in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the field delimiter in your file is ^ - based on the data you've shown as being loaded. If this is the case then you'll need to use a file format, either defined against your stage or in your select statement

[File formats when querying stages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html#optional-parameters)

Comment: Thanks @NickW. I made it work. Just one question, would I need to remove the staging files as mentioned https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/remove.html or would they be remove automatically after the successful load? copy provides purge true is there any such option with merge?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you'd have to delete them manually. In effect all you've done is run a select against the data, treating the stage as an external table, so there would be no reason for Snowflake to delete it